# What is the definition of value?

Tags: number-theory

Imagine a number line. Each number has a value, but how is value defined? For rational numbers this is self evident, but what about real numbers? For example, we know that $\pi>e$, because $\pi>3$ while $e<3$. So here we have a rational number between them. This however doesn't tell us the value of either $\pi$ or $e$. Do we have to use asymptotically approaching rational numbers to define the value of a real number through a procedure with an infinite number of steps? Or is there a different method?

Comment: Inherently a number line  is associated with a metric and one possible definition of 'value' is $|x-0|$, the distance from the origin.

Comment: Imagine I know a lot of math, but somehow I have never seen the symbol $\pi$ used. Now, could you please tell me: which number is $\pi$? A decent answer to my question is probably an answer to your problem.

Comment: Any real number can be defined by $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ for some rational sequence $a_n$. If the number is irrational then why would you expect a method containing finitely many steps to produce its value to arbitrary accuracy?

Comment: So if for rational numbers it is self-evident to you, then how do you define the value of a rational number? (I would define the value of a number to be just that number, but that can't be what you have in mind, as that would make your question pointless).

Comment: What do you mean by “value”? I’m assuming it’s something like the decimal expansion of a number, e.g., $\pi=3.1415...$. Value is not a formal term in this context, so it does not have a definition. In a sense, you do need to refer to arbitrary approximations to get a real number: real numbers are typically realised with direct reference to their rational approximations as something called Dedekind cuts or something similar. Also, this is analysis, not number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you say, in general, we have to use asymptotically approaching rational numbers to define the value of a real number through a procedure with an infinite number of steps. Of course, because rational numbers, such as $3$, are also real numbers, sometimes a real number can be defined finitely.

Answer (score 0):

Irrational numbers can be defined in many ways. I will use $\pi$ and $e$ as examples as you used them in your question.

$e$ can be defined as:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}=e$$
$\pi$ is defined as the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter; $$\pi=\frac{c}{2r}$$
where $c$ is the circumference of a circle and $r$ is the radius of this same circle.

In general though, irrational numbers can be defined by approaching them with an infinite number of steps as you say in your question, such as as the limit of an infinite rational sequence.